# Why can't I find the Controllers folder in Visual studio 2010

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm creating an ASP.net website, I am trying to find the controllers folder but I can't see it listed:

Here is a picture of what's listed:

http://s27.postimg.org/kjy7tjr9v/Asp_net_Images_Folder.jpg

Answer (score 2):

A asp.net web forms project will not have a controllers folder. Make sure you set it up as an MVC project.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert your *Web Site* to a *Web Application* and then add the MVC components from the nuget package here:

> http://www.nuget.org/packages/AspNetMvc